# Is it possible to further customize the format of git log based on some built-in options?

Tags: git, git-log

I want a prettier look git log.
I'm current using `git log --branches --remotes --tags --graph --decorate --oneline`, which is already pretty good.

But it doesn't show the commiter names and date, what I want to do is do some further customization based on the above built-in options.

Is it possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pretty git branch graphs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1057564/pretty-git-branch-graphs)

Answer (score 0):

first of you I suggest to use `--all` instead of `--branches --remotes --tags` to make your command line more compact.
Also, instead of having a very long commandline you can add your alias in the `.gitconfig` file.

I use the following two aliasesL

```
[alias]
    superlog = log --graph --all --decorate --pretty=oneline
    superlogextended = log --graph --all --decorate
```

superlogextended looks like what you are asking for.
After you add the alias in `~/.gitconfig` just use it like this:

```
git superlog
git superlogextended
```

Comment: For what it's worth, `--all` is (subtly?) different from `--branches --remotes --tags`: the former means *all references* while the latter three, used together, mean *all branches, remote-tracking branches, and tags*. The difference is that *all references* adds `refs/notes/*` and `refs/stash` if they exist, plus anything else living in `refs/` if any such things exist. (That aside, I use `--all` myself.)